# Bash: a script to find all directories with no "permission denied"?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a script in bash without "awk" to find every directories that can be accessed.

I did not see any post about this issue.

Thanks

Comment: What, specifically, do you mean by "accessed". A list of all directories that the user lacks read access to? What have you tried? Is there any specific point in this script that you are stuck on?

Comment: Also, why not awk?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you meant readable directories, `find` (at least the GNU version) makes this pretty easy:

```
find /path/to/root -type d -readable
```

which could similarly be used to find unreadable dirs,

```
find /path/to/root -type d ! -readable
```

There is also a `-writable` option which does what you'd expect, and also `-executable` which for directories means searchable.

Comment: I meant directories with no message "permission denied" when trying to access via "cd"